# Outlook Exchange change email from name base on send

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Is it possible to change the From Name of an email (not the sending address) when sending an email from Outlook Exchange?
Is there any add-in that can help us achieve this?
I can see with Exchange only admin can change the sending from name. Is there an alternative?

Comment: It seems you need to correct the GAL entry properties to see a different name.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev but this will be controlled by an Admin and not by the end user. while the end user need the flexibility to change it ad-hoc. Any alternatives?

Comment: You can try to create a corresponding contact in your Outlook's address book (Contacts folder) with the required name and email. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't do that out of the box. The latest version of hosted (M365) Exchange allows to configure a mailbox to send as one of its proxy SMTP addresses, but the sender display name will still be the same.

You can try to use an addin like [Proxy Manager](https://www.dimastr.com/proxyman/) (I am its author) - besides allowing to send through any of the mailbox proxy addresses, it also allows an end-user to change the sender display name.